# Can't get Mapbox SDK to recognize fuzzyMatch property in geocodeForward request

Tags: javascript, mapbox

The geocodeForward endpoint should have support for a `fuzzyMatch` property, as seen here: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#forward-geocoding

I've implemented it like so:

```
import MapboxClient from "mapbox";
const mapbox = new MapboxClient(env.MAPBOX_KEY);

const fullAddress = `${address} ${city}, ${state} ${zip_code}`;

mapbox.geocodeForward(fullAddress, {
  country: "us",
  limit: 1,
  fuzzyMatch: false,
  types: "address",
  autocomplete: false
}, function (err, data, res) {
  console.log('err', err)
  console.log('data', data)
  console.log('res', res)
});
```

I put in an invalid address to test, but still get a good result, because the fuzzy match is still working. See screenshot below of the query string params (via Chrome devtools)

[Query String Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpksj.png)

Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it actually appears that this property was never implemented in the library. This is a known issue. It does not appear that anybody is working to resolve this.

See issue below:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/issues/377